# "Force unwrapping" in Flow?

Tags: redux, flowtype

I have this helper function in my reducer, which has the given state:

```js
type CustomerCollection = { [number]: Customer }

type CustomerState = {
  +customers: ?CustomerCollection,
  +newItem: ?(Customer | Review),
  +searchResults: ?(Customer[]),
  +error: ?string,
  +isLoading: boolean
};

function customerWithReview(review: Review): Customer {
    const id: number = review.customerId;
    const oldCustomer: Customer = state.customers[id];
    const newReviews: Review[] = [review, ...oldCustomer.reviews];
    return Object.assign(oldCustomer, { reviews: newReviews });
  }
```

I get a Flow error on the `id` of `const oldCustomer: Customer = state.customers[id];` saying `Cannot get state.customers[id] because an index signature declaring the expected key/value type is missing in null or undefined`.

This is happening because of the nullable/optional `?CustomerCollection` type of `state.customers`.

I can silence the error by making sure `customers` isn't null:

```js
 if (state.customers) {
      const oldCustomer: Customer = state.customers[id];
      const newReviews: Review[] = [review, ...oldCustomer.reviews];
      return Object.assign(oldCustomer, { reviews: newReviews });
    }
```

But then the problem just goes up the chain because I don't have anything to return from the function.

I can certainly expand it to:

```js
  function customerWithReview(review: Review): Customer {
    if (!state.customers) {
      return new Customer();
    } else {
      const id: number = review.customerId;
      const oldCustomer: Customer = state.customers[id];
      const newReviews: Review[] = [review, ...oldCustomer.reviews];
      return Object.assign(oldCustomer, { reviews: newReviews });
    }
  }
```

But in actual practice, the action that gets us to this branch of the reducer will never be called if `state.customers` is `null`, and we'd never return `new Customer()` and would have no use for it if we did. `state.customers` is nullable in order to tell the difference between "we haven't fetched the customers yet (`state.customers == null`)" and "we've fetched the customers but there are none (`state.customers == {}`).

It would be a lot easier if I could just assert that `state.customers` would always exist in these cases, which in Swift I would do with force-unwrapping:
`const oldCustomer: Customer = state.customers![id];`

Can I do anything like this with Flow?

Or, given that only my `GET_CUSTOMERS_FAILURE` action would ever deal with `state.customers == null`, is there some other way to restructure my reducer so that this is a little easier? An entirely separate `fetchReducer` that is has a nullable customer collection while the rest of the actions fall under a different reducer?

Comment: You could throw an error if `state.customers === null` so that Flow doesn't complain about an invalid return type and you get a nice error during development if `state.customers` is ever `null` where you don't expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `invariant` function (Check that it works [here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYQE5QLxQN5QCWAJgFxQB2cqARpgDRQYQBuhEA7guQIIYYBDEAB4ASq3YcAfFAC+AbgBQoSFHFtOOfFADGiFOgwBJMpWp0sCxcvDR4SNJhjIANi4g7ghZBS0EA2lS0mAC65PYGmHLWKnb6jhgAysACwNC4eIpQUADUeg6G3FAA-BEJzm4eXj70WbkUnEZpqOTFABRlhlAAPmoSnACUtdk5CBACGDoAFuIIcC7ARe2dmP4hQ3U5mBjIGK1IGIQUAObDuYQIADLIAsRHx+Q0yK7jFIpWisQeLhPQLBNQJCpCDheKGZLApRfHQ-ZhQABmcAonm8viO-0OAgowDaA3ILGQJCUikRyOqvnykQwAHVCMAZv0OG1mBoOOR1JI8bAwVFMtlsjofEgiKYghYtCzJAA6SkJExKbIASHRE0IWJxQLSMp5GAQjAA5AA5ZC6HUIKBY4hQIxQYg+AA6+uAUAA1hRkBwoBwpiB9QMFfzBRRha5iCs9tyClFcJqINqo7r-CQQgGBULnQ0OBzOEVsxw1lp-JLOIwpWXQ+GpcWuCm6tlmMA4BhfAB5GgAKyqUoECAQhGOFDaFZ1jAI1aKmbz5tk-veQA)):

```
type Customer = { id: number, reviews: Array<Review> };
type Review = { customerId: number };

type CustomerCollection = { [number]: Customer }

type CustomerState = {
  +customers: ?CustomerCollection,
  +newItem: ?(Customer | Review),
  +searchResults: ?(Customer[]),
  +error: ?string,
  +isLoading: boolean
};

declare var state: CustomerState;
declare function invariant(): void;

function customerWithReview(review: Review): Customer {
    const id: number = review.customerId;
    invariant(state.customers, 'No customers and I don\'t know why');
    const oldCustomer: Customer = state.customers[id];
    const newReviews: Review[] = [review, ...oldCustomer.reviews];
    return Object.assign(oldCustomer, { reviews: newReviews });
}
```

You can implement it somewhere in your project and import when necessary.

You can implement it like this:

```
export function invariant<T>(value: ?T, falsyErrorMessage: string, errorParams?: Object): void {
  if (!value) {
    log.error(falsyErrorMessage, errorParams || {});
    throw new Error(INVARIANT_ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the name of the function is [hard-coded](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/112) in flow.

Alternative variant is just to add an `if` and to throw an error in your `customerWithReview` function directly.